# Ace editor, how to turn on block selection without having to press alt

Tags: javascript, cursor, ace-editor

Normally in ace-editor, to if you hold down the alt key, while making a selection, it will select it in block form which i think is called block selection.

How do i make it so that it is in block selection as standard, and pressing alt changes it to normal selection instead.

I think it has something to do with this

```
function onMouseDown(e) {
var ev = e.domEvent;
var alt = ev.altKey;
var shift = ev.shiftKey;
var ctrl = e.getAccelKey();
var button = e.getButton();

var editor = e.editor;
var selection = editor.selection;
var isMultiSelect = editor.inMultiSelectMode;
var pos = e.getDocumentPosition();
var cursor = selection.getCursor();
var inSelection = e.inSelection() || (selection.isEmpty() && isSamePoint(pos, cursor));


var mouseX = e.x, mouseY = e.y;
var onMouseSelection = function(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
};

var blockSelect = function() {
    var newCursor = editor.renderer.pixelToScreenCoordinates(mouseX, mouseY);
    var cursor = session.screenToDocumentPosition(newCursor.row, newCursor.column);

    if (isSamePoint(screenCursor, newCursor)
        && isSamePoint(cursor, selection.selectionLead))
        return;
    screenCursor = newCursor;

    editor.selection.moveCursorToPosition(cursor);
    editor.selection.clearSelection();
    editor.renderer.scrollCursorIntoView();

    editor.removeSelectionMarkers(rectSel);
    rectSel = selection.rectangularRangeBlock(screenCursor, screenAnchor);
    rectSel.forEach(editor.addSelectionMarker, editor);
    editor.updateSelectionMarkers();
};
```

which i found in ace.js between lines 15479 and 15528, and this;

```
 else if (alt && button == 0) {
    e.stop();

    if (isMultiSelect && !ctrl)
        selection.toSingleRange();
    else if (!isMultiSelect && ctrl)
        selection.addRange();

    var rectSel = [];
    if (shift) {
        screenAnchor = session.documentToScreenPosition(selection.lead);
        blockSelect();
    } else {
        selection.moveCursorToPosition(pos);
        selection.clearSelection();
    }
```

line 15561, and 15567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done **without** altering **ace.js** by replacing the **onMouseDown** function stored in the editor's **_eventRegistry.mousedown[1]** with a wrapper that calls the same function with an inverted value for **ev.altKey** as follows.

```
editor._eventRegistry.mousedown[1] = (func => e => func({
  ...e, ...e.__proto__,
  getButton: () => e.getButton(),
  domEvent: { ...e.domEvent,
    altKey: !e.domEvent.altKey,
    shiftKey: e.domEvent.shiftKey,
    ctrlKey: e.domEvent.ctrlKey,
  },
}))(editor._eventRegistry.mousedown[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as simple as changing this line...

```
var alt = ev.altKey;
```

to this...

```
var alt = !ev.altKey;
```

Comment: yep, perfect, thanks. also is there a way to alter this in a different javascript file rather than in ace.js?

Comment: No - it will have to be in that file.  I'd recommend adding a suffix to the filename so you know it's an amended version and doesn't get overwritten if you update it in the future :)