# reversing perceived input from keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, alt

I would like to make is so that while the alt key is not being pressed, the webpage responds as if it is being pressed, and vice versa.

Comment: I am using ace editor and while pressing alt, block selection is enabled, and while not pressing alt it isn't. I want block selection enabled normally, and just reversing the effect that the alt key has seems to be the easiest way even if it has some horrible unforeseen side effects. Here is a link to that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081242/ace-editor-how-to-turn-on-block-selection-without-having-to-press-alt

Comment: Working on the code on your other question would be much simpler than mimicking the alt key.  I'll post something on there.